# Extend RxJS Observable class with operators

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs, rxjs5

How can `Observable` class be extended by applying built-in RxJS operators to it?

I would like to do something like this:

```
class TruthyObservable extends Observable {
  constructor(subscriber) {
    super(subscriber);

    return this.filter(x => x);
  }
}

class TruthyMappedObservable extends TruthyObservable {
  constructor(subscriber) {
    super(subscriber);

    return this.map(x => `'${x}'`);
  }
}
```

Can this be done without constructor return?

Comment: Where do you expect the `.filter(x => x);` to be added? I'd understand it if you were trying to always append a standard RxJS operator to your custom operator.

Comment: @martin I expect that the operator will be added on class instantiation, before any other operator.

Comment: An operator is not a class which extends `Rx.Observable`. It's a method on its prototype. Anyway, I guess you meant `this.filter(Boolean)`?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes. The question isn't limited to `filter` though, it's there for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pretty much depends on what you want to do but let's say you want to make a `TruthyObservable` that behaves very much like the default `Observable.create(...)` but passes only even numbers:

```
import { Observable, Observer, Subscriber, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

class TruthyObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {

    constructor(subscribe?: <R>(this: Observable<T>, subscriber: Subscriber<R>) => any) {
        if (subscribe) {
            let oldSubscribe = subscribe;
            subscribe = (obs: Subscriber<any>) => {
                obs = this.appendOperators(obs);
                return oldSubscribe.call(this, obs);
            };
        }

        super(subscribe);
    }

    private appendOperators(obs: Subscriber<any>) {
        let subject = new Subject();

        subject
            .filter((val: number) => val % 2 == 0)
            .subscribe(obs);

        return new Subscriber(subject);
    }

}

let o = new TruthyObservable<number>((obs: Observer<number>) => {
    obs.next(3);
    obs.next(6);
    obs.next(7);
    obs.next(8);
});

o.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

This prints to console:

```
6
8
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/recuto/3/edit?js,console

Usually classes inheriting `Observable` override the `_subscribe()` method that actually makes the subscription internally but in ours case we want to use the callback where we can emit values by ourselves (since this Observable doesn't emit anything itself). Method `_subscribe()` is overshadowed by `_subscribe` property if it exists so we wouldn't be able to append any operators to it if we just overrode this method. That's why I wrap `_subscribe` in the constructor with another function and then pass all values through a `Subject` chained with `filter()` in `appendOperators()` method. Note that I replaced the original Observer with the `Subject` at `obs = this.appendOperators(obs)`.

At the end when I call eg. `obs.next(3);` I'm in fact pushing values to the `Subject` that filters them and passes them to the original `Observer`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get what you need with custom operator:

```
    Observable.prototype.truthy = function truthy() {
        return this.filter(x => x);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it can be done this way. However, the question is about how it can be done through inheritance, also I don't intend to modify the prototype.

Comment: @estus, Can you provide me with use case/example for/of `TruthyObservable `?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in understanding how RxJS can be properly extended, `Observable` in particular. I intended to use extended `Observable` as Angular 2 service, it plays better with classes in Typescript.

Comment: @estus Inheriting from what? Operators are not objects or classes, and have no base class;they are just methods. You would extend `Rx.Observable` to create an observable with some kind of modified behavior, not an operator.

Comment: @torazaburo Inheriting from `Observable`. I don't intend to extend operators, just apply them to `this` instance.